# css table row decimal counter

Tags: css, html-table

By using the below code, I can have the table rows counted. In this case, it will return 4,5,6.

```css
table {
        counter-reset: rowNumber 3;
    }
    
    table tr {
        counter-increment: rowNumber;
    }
    
    table tr td:first-child::before {
        content: counter(rowNumber);
        min-width: 1em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>blue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>black</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What I wanted was to have them numbered like 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 (...).

I tried to use

```
content: counter(rowNumber, ".") ". ";
```

but then all numbers disappear.

Comment: `content: "3." counter(rowNumber);` ?

Comment: @ATP Thank you. I changed the starting number to 1 and for what I need, it does work with your suggestion